# How can I split the sentence between two specific words to put in a variable later on?

Tags: python

This is just an example of my question:

```
    string = "This is just a random sentence"
    print(string)
```

How can I split the sentence between `is` and `just` to put in a variable later on?

Comment: We love that you're here and what have you tried so we can help you fix it. You need to give us your work.

Comment: In C# and VB.NET there are string commands like Right(string,n), Left(string,n), which pull off the left side and right side of a string at position n.  There's also Split(string,"just") command, which could split your string into two strings.  Thus, look at string manipulation commands in python. You should also be able to find out how many positions from the left any word is within a string.  In VB.NET this is called InStr(string,"just").

Answer (score 0):

It'll need to be something unique to the sentence, or a specific length.

Going the length route you can easily do:

```
x = "elephant"
string[:8] + x + string[7:]
```

If you do a string split on space you'll have to reassemble the entire thing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

are you wanting to do something like this?

```
string = "This is just a random sentence" 
x = "INSERT" 
split1 = string[:8]
split2 = string[8:]
newString = split1 + x + split2
print(split1)
print(split2)
print(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "This is just a random sentence"
splits = string.split('just')
variable = 'alex'

string = x[0]+variable+' just'+x[1]
print(string)
```

output:

```
This is alex just a random sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit much, but you can use regular expressions like (untested, may have typos):

```
import re
string = 'This is just a random sentence'
pattern = '^(.*)just(.*)$'
a = re.search(pattern, string)
print(a.group(1))
print(a.group(2))

pattern2 = '^(.*just)(.*)$'
b = re.search(pattern2, string)
print(b.group(1))
print(b.group(2))
```

Using the pattern with or without the word 'just' depending on your goal. And you could also leave the spaces around ' just ' to not get them in the groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make these kind of "statement" to print out, try something like this:

```py
>>> s1 = "This string has %d characters"
>>> l1 = len(s1)
>>> s2 = s1 % (l1,)
>>> l2 = len(s2)
>>> s3 = s1 % (l2,)
>>> print(s3)
This string has 29 characters
```

There might be an issue when your string will be one character longer. So maybe you will need to check `l2` is equal to `len(s3)`.

Good luck.